# iPad center custom modal view

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an application with custom modal view controller and this controller is inside navigation controller here is my code:

```
CalendarViewController *calendarViewController = [[CalendarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil];

[calendarViewController setDelegate:self];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:calendarViewController];
[navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navigationController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 630, 555);
navigationController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Problem is that this navigation controller is not center on screen. Location of this screen is right side of ipad. Is there a solution how center this custom controller. Thanks a lot.